# breeze.js how to do sum on column values --- sum(UnitsInTotal)

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, breeze

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with knockout and Breeze, and trying to sum a column value `(sum(UnitsInTotal))`.

I can do it in Knockout foreach, but to avoid it in cshtml (I have my breeze based column filter's which works fine.), I would like to add it on my  Breeze based javascript code itself.  Any help ...

```
var serviceAddress = "breeze/Values",
    em = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceAddress),
    getProducts = function () {
        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Product");
        var promise = em.executeQuery(query);
        return promise;
    },
    getSumOfUnitsInTotal = function () {
        var query = new breeze,EntityQuery("Product").where...
        var promise=em.executeQuery(query);
        return promise;
}
```

I am not sure , how to do `SUM(UnitsInTotal)` which is a column with numeric Data.
I would like to know , how to write the Breeze query to get the SUM value. I am new to breeze.

Comment: Can you provide some code here ? What is `UnitsInTotal` ? Anything, seriously. It seems that you don't care about your problem, why should others ?

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense and contains no code to understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: var serviceAddress = "breeze/Values",
        em = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceAddress),
        getProducts = function () {
            var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Product");
            var promise = em.executeQuery(query);
            return promise;
        },
        getFilteredProducts = function (property, operation, criteria) {
            var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Product").where(property, operation, criteria);
            var promise = em.executeQueryLocally(query);
            return promise;
        },

Comment: Product is the SqlServer table .One of the column is UnitsInTotal. I am trying to sum the value in Breeze , Is it possible ? If ot what is the best sugg??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it.

### Here is my BreezeQuery.

```
 getItemTotal=function() {var queryAggUnitsInTotal= new breeze.EntityQuery("Product").select("UnitPrice");
   return  em.executeQuery(queryAggUnitsInTotal)
   .then(calculateUnitsInTotal ).fail(handleFail);
```

---

calculateUnitsInTotal = `function (data)` `{var unitsInTotal = 0;`

```
       data.results.forEach(function (result)
       {
           unitsInTotal = unitsInTotal + result.UnitPrice;
       });
    return unitsInTotal; --ko.observable(unitsInTotal);--- Sum of UnitpriceValues
```

//  Total value of my UnitPrice column.-- thru ko.observableArray, append and used in cshtml.I am trying to avoid too many knockout calculation at cshtml.// This approach my cshtml looks better and very clean. 
--Hope this help some dev's.